# Java outofbounds errors

Tags: java, arrays

Currently I'm writing the Game of Life program. However when I try to print out the random array, nothing happens and when I try to run the prebuilt grid I get an out of bounds error.

Please keep in mind I have tried to debug myself and have had this looked over by one other peer and he could not figure it out either.

Any help would be appreciated. (I apologize for the lack of comments. I realize how unprofessional this is, but currently I'm just trying to get it to work.)

Here is my main file

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Life
{
    private int k;
    private int l;
    private boolean[][] lifeArray = new boolean[k][l];
    private int counter = 0;

    public Life(int thisK, int thisL) 
    {
        lifeArray = new boolean[k][l];
        k = thisK;
        l = thisL;
    }

    public void initialGrid()
    {
        int r = lifeArray.length / 3; // Set up a third of the way down
        int c = lifeArray[0].length / 3; // Set up a third of the way over
        for (int a = 0; a < lifeArray.length; a++)
            for (int b = 0; b < lifeArray[0].length; b++)
                lifeArray[a][b] = false; // initialize the array to false

        lifeArray[r][c + 3] = lifeArray[r][c + 8] = true; // top row
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 1] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 2] = true; // middle 2
                                                                    // le.t
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 9] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 10] = true; // middle 4
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 4] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 5] = true; // middle 4
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 6] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 7] = true; // middle 2
                                                                    // right
        lifeArray[r + 2][c + 3] = lifeArray[r + 2][c + 8] = true; // bottom row
    }

    public void randomBuild() {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++) {
                if (rn.nextInt(10) <= 3) {
                    lifeArray[i][j] = true;
                    System.out.println("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        printBoard();
    }

    public void fileInput(String theFile, String directory) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(theFile, directory);
        Scanner scanIt = new Scanner(file);

    }

    public void prebuiltGrid() {
        //clearGrid();
        initialGrid();
        printBoard();

    }

    public void clearGrid() {
        // Initializes array to all false
        for (int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++) {
                lifeArray[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void nextGen() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++) {
                if (lifeArray[i + 1][j] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i - 1][j] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i][j + 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i][j - 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i + 1][j + 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i - 1][j - 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter >= 4 || counter <= 1) {
                    lifeArray[i][j] = false;
                } else if (counter == 3) {
                    lifeArray[i][j] = true;
                }

                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printBoard() 
    {
        int lineCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++)
            {
                if(lifeArray[i][j] == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                lineCount++;


            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my runner

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Life
{
    private int k;
    private int l;
    private boolean[][] lifeArray = new boolean[k][l];
    private int counter = 0;

    public Life(int thisK, int thisL) 
    {
        lifeArray = new boolean[k][l];
        k = thisK;
        l = thisL;
    }

    public void initialGrid()
    {
        int r = lifeArray.length / 3; // Set up a third of the way down
        int c = lifeArray[0].length / 3; // Set up a third of the way over
        for (int a = 0; a < lifeArray.length; a++)
            for (int b = 0; b < lifeArray[0].length; b++)
                lifeArray[a][b] = false; // initialize the array to false

        lifeArray[r][c + 3] = lifeArray[r][c + 8] = true; // top row
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 1] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 2] = true; // middle 2
                                                                    // le.t
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 9] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 10] = true; // middle 4
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 4] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 5] = true; // middle 4
        lifeArray[r + 1][c + 6] = lifeArray[r + 1][c + 7] = true; // middle 2
                                                                    // right
        lifeArray[r + 2][c + 3] = lifeArray[r + 2][c + 8] = true; // bottom row
    }

    public void randomBuild() {
        Random rn = new Random();
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++) {
                if (rn.nextInt(10) <= 3) {
                    lifeArray[i][j] = true;
                    System.out.println("*");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        printBoard();
    }

    public void fileInput(String theFile, String directory) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(theFile, directory);
        Scanner scanIt = new Scanner(file);

    }

    public void prebuiltGrid() {
        //clearGrid();
        initialGrid();
        printBoard();

    }

    public void clearGrid() {
        // Initializes array to all false
        for (int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++) {
                lifeArray[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void nextGen() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++) {
                if (lifeArray[i + 1][j] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i - 1][j] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i][j + 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i][j - 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i + 1][j + 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (lifeArray[i - 1][j - 1] == true) {
                    counter++;
                }

                if (counter >= 4 || counter <= 1) {
                    lifeArray[i][j] = false;
                } else if (counter == 3) {
                    lifeArray[i][j] = true;
                }

                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void printBoard() 
    {
        int lineCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lifeArray.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < lifeArray[0].length; j++)
            {
                if(lifeArray[i][j] == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                lineCount++;


            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please include the error in your post, especially the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k and l are 0 on initialising lifeArray.

```
public Life(int thisK, int thisL) 
{
    k = thisK;
    l = thisL;
    lifeArray = new boolean[k][l];
}
```